# What's the AmE and BrE for "tartaruga"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, american-english, british-english, slang

In Italian  the term ***["tartaruga](https://www.google.it/search?q=tartaruga%20addominale&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT606IT607&oq=tartaruga%20addominale%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.10627j0j8&hl=it&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)"  (turtle)*** is used also to refer to ***well defined abdominal muscles*** on the notion that they look like a turtle shell:

[image]

[image]

Is there a slang/colloquial term or short phrase to refer to "defined addominal muscles" in AmE or BrE?

Comment: **abs** abbreviation for abdominal muscles. An example of *abs* are the stomach muscles of Mike "The Situation" from the reality tv show *Jersey Shore*.  Read more at http://www.yourdictionary.com/abs#mLzAuxfBz2PkJ8Uc.99

Comment: Hi Josh - just a curiosity - you appear to write flawless idiomatic English (I've always assumed it's your mother tongue), it's surprising you haven't heard "six-pack"? It's pretty common.

Comment: @JoeBlow - no, never heard that before. Sorry for that.

Comment: Just for anyone googling here, there is another very common Americanism (or American politicalism) "Joe six-pack".  The two are **totally unrelated**.  "Joe six-pack" simply means "the typical working-class guy" and has no relationship to the bodybuilding slang.

Comment: @Joe yes, that six pack is beer, not abs.

Comment: I always thought "Joe six-pack" referred to the belief that alcohol was one of the five essential human food groups - the other four being salt, sugar, caffeine, and fat.

Comment: @Joe Blow: My understanding of "Joe Six-pack" (just as a native speaker of American and former TWCG) is not "the typical working-class guy", but the subset of TWCGs who've drunk lots of six-packs and so acquired the beer gut and associated characteristics.

Comment: Joe Six-Pack is a member of the working class who likes beer.  Six-pack abs are what OP is talking about.  Having a six-pack usually means literally having a package of 6 beers. I am using American English.

Comment: what's a TWCG ??

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can say that somebody has a ***[six pack](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/six-pack?q=six%20pack)***.

> *informal* - A man’s set of visibly well-developed abdominal muscles.

Or perhaps even an ***[eight pack](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/eight_pack)***.

You can also say that someone has ***[washboard](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/washboard)*** abs or a washboard stomach, although commentators on this answer suggest that this is used more in fitness circles to describe a flatter, less "ripped" set of abs than those in your picture:

> [AS MODIFIER] Denoting a man’s stomach that is lean and has well-defined muscles:

Comment: Are these AmE terms?

Comment: I can only speak for BrEng at the moment but I'm sure one of my transatlantic friends can confirm its AmEng usage for us.

Comment: I'm a fighter, trainer and bodybuilder. And with all respect, I'd like to tell you that *washboard abs* is an insult to the guy in the picture. *Washboard abs* are flat and people who possess those are way weaker than people with *ripped abs*.

Comment: Perhaps but the term is still used in that context.  I agree that I'd prefer ripped abs to a washboard stomach but I'm only answering what I believe to be true and I offer the answer as an addition, not competition, to your own answer.

Comment: @vickyace - in what sense do they differ? The definitions  are very similar.

Comment: http://www.telegraph.co.uk/men/active/10412735/Six-pack-abs-workout-how-to-get-a-washboard-stomach.html

Comment: @Ste We are here to improve not compete. You are right that they are similar in dictionary definition but are not in reality. *Washboard abs* are flat and usually possessed by the likes of jennifer lopez, shakira, that twilight guys. *ripped abs* are possessed by people like Rob Riches, terry crews, the 300 movie guys, and even girls like andrea cadavid, michelle lewin, anlela segra and others. (sorry for late reply, Internet is unreliable in India)

Comment: @vickyace I'll bow to your superior knowledge about fitness and our discussion remains here for posterity.  I have definitely heard the term "washboard" used outside of fitness circles to describe a six pack. :)

Comment: I agree with @vickyace. Washboard is used a lot. It is actually meant for a flat stomach with slightly visible abs.

Comment: You might add a line about the variant *eight pack* (https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/eight_pack). By the way, AmE here, and I've heard all three of these in widespread use.

Comment: say @vickyace - you know, it's true that experts would make the distinction between washboard abs, and a six-pack.  but it would be common for "civilians" to simply use the term "washboard abs" to mean "any pretty good stomach", i.e., not the usual 50 pounds of overweight.  in any event, "six-pack" is the exact answer here to the "turtle" equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

Try **ripped abs**

[MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ripped)

> having high muscle definition

Answer (score 1):

You could also say: ***shredded abs***.

**shredded** — [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/shredded)

> 2 *informal* Having well-defined or well-developed muscles; muscular

Example:

> a step-by-step plan that will help you achieve *shredded abs* in as
>   little as 76 workouts